# How to close AlertDialog with a mouse click?

Tags: android

I have an `AlertDialog` with a short information about my application and I would like to close it without any buttons, just with a mouse click somewhere on my AlertDialog. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
mAlertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Using this if you click outside the dialog it will get dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the reference to AlertDialog and on mouse click, call mAlertDialog.dismiss() to dismiss the dialog.